# How to access the google credentials json file by placing in app folder of project and how to pass that path to the GoogleCredentials

Tags: android

Here am accessing the credentials file by placing file in raw folder I am passing the path like this

```
GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("android.resource://com.tvs.digi.dmsapp/raw/dms_app_google"))
```

And I am getting below error

```
android.resource:/com.tvs.digi.dmsapp/raw/dms_app_google: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly use below code for access your json file.

Update: 2
Can you please try to set the environment variable by adding json file path.

[image: Set enviroment varibale]

```
val inputStream = this.getAssets().open("XXXXX-6e000f81XXXX.json")
val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream)        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatform"))
val credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)
val speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: while accessing this code  try (SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create()) {

Comment: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

Comment: @ArunKumar I updated my answer, How you can set environment variable path (Put your json file in your local system as well) in android studio. Please check and let me know if you still facing the same error.

Comment: Same error am getting after setting the environment variable also

Comment: @ArunKumar I am also trying to achieve Speaker Diarization using speech client api, but I am not succeeded. 
Please check this link [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437181/speaker-diarization-from-audio-file-android  ] I fixed other issues but I am unable to get speakers from audio file.
I am also facing the same error during this task, but I fixed by adding a variable path like which I added in the android studio.
Let me try more.